# Background animation on hover returns to the start point when executing finished

Tags: html, css, background-color, css-animations

I have an image with transparent background. I would like to make a css3 background animation when the mouse hovers it.

This is the CSS i'm using:

```css
@keyframes in
{
from {background-color: #fff;}
to {background-color: #900;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes in /*chrome-safari*/
{
from {background-color: #fff;}
to {background-color: #900;}
}

img {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
}

img:hover {    
    animation: in 0.5s;
    -webkit-animation: in 0.5s;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

The animations work, the problem is that when the animation reaches the end point (`background-color: #900`), it returns to the start point (`background-color: #fff`).

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C5A5Q/1/)

How do i make the background permanent after the animation?

Comment: If you are talking about only for the hover state, then add "animation-fill-mode: forwards;" but if you are talking about after the hover state - than the answer below.

Comment: @drip Yes i'm talking about making the animation end-point permanent while the mouse is over the image

Comment: Then like I said the fill-mode will do the trick: http://jsfiddle.net/C5A5Q/4/

Comment: @drip it doesn't work for me

Comment: Check once again, forgot to add webkit prefix for Chorme (firefox user xd)

Comment: @drip Ok, actually i changed that property to _both_, it looks better when the mouse goes out of the image, can you post this as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just adding the fill-mode do the trick:

```
animation-fill-mode: forwards;
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C5A5Q/4/)